# Linq (to entities) serialization into XElement (with joins and group by)

Tags: c#, xml, linq

What I am doing is query the database with Linq to entities to build an xml document. Before I was using store procedures with "for xml" clause and using an xmlreader, but now I am trying to stick with only one model to query the database, Linq to Entities.

Now the code below is the best I could come with, but I really hate I could not find a better solution to build the XML at once without having to first query the db and then iterate to create the XElements.
I could not create XElements directly in the select because the class doesn't have a parameterless creator, and as far as I know there's no ToXElement() in Linq.

Anyone who did similar things before has any better idea on how to do that?

```
    var bus = from bs in db.mela_buddies_store
              join mu in db.mela_users on bs.buddyId equals mu.userid
              join mup in db.mela_users_picnames on mu.userid equals mup.userid into pics
              from up in pics.DefaultIfEmpty()
              join bc in db.mela_buddies_store on mu.userid equals bc.buddyId into cntr
              from hm in cntr.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where bs.userId == lu.guid
              group bs by new
              {
                id = bs.ID,
                displayname = mu.displayname,
                gender = mu.gender,
                picname = up.picname
              }
              into final
              select new {
                id = final.Key.id,
                displayname = final.Key.displayname,
                gender = final.Key.gender,
                picname = final.Key.picname,
                hm = final.Count()
              };

    XElement xe = new XElement("buddies",
      new XElement("userid", lu.userid),
      bus.ToList().Select(bs =>
        new XElement("buddy",
          new XElement("id", bs.id),
          new XElement("displayname", bs.displayname),
          new XElement("gender", bs.gender),
          new XElement("picname", bs.picname),
          new XElement("hm", bs.hm)
          )));
```

Comment: See my comment to @xeondev below. Linq to Entities (differently from Linq to SQL) do not accept a parametrized constructor (after the select). As far as I understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XElement constructor can accept IEnumerable so I would simply put in the query as parameter. A sample for northwind DB Products table, it should work with more complicated query too.

```
var xml = new XElement("products",
    from prod in ctx.Products.ToList()
    select new XElement("product", 
        new XElement("id", prod.ProductID),
        new XElement("name", prod.ProductName) 
        )
    );
```

Update: 
It seems join and group by is OK too. I have grouped products by supplier.

```
var xml = new XElement("suppliers",
    (from prod in ctx.Products
     join supp in ctx.Suppliers on prod.SupplierID equals supp.SupplierID
     group prod by new { id = prod.SupplierID, name = supp.CompanyName }).ToList()
     .Select(xe => new XElement("supplier",
             new XElement("id", xe.Key.id),
             new XElement("name", xe.Key.name),
             new XElement("count", xe.Count())
             )
         )
    );
```

Comment: Mhhh... That was precisely my frist attempt, but I was getting the error "no parameterless constructor defined for this object", in fact in linq to entities I don't think you can put any parametrized constructor after the select. Or am I not understanding something?

Comment: @MaxFavilli I have only tried in LinqPad and it works. But with EF i got the same error as you.

Comment: @MaxFavilli In Entity Framework, you must call .ToList() after retrieving, and my sample works.

Comment: I like it, but... Question, all the ToList() are fetching from the database, correct? While the other way round one big fetch is supposed to be executed?

Comment: Yes, ToList() will cause full table scan, but i have refactored the query to execute one fetch.